# Skip RenewTicketIfOld during ajax call to a specific action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I use `setInterval` with an ajax call to check for new messages every minute. This call extends authentication cookie (because I have slidingExpiration set to true), thus authentication never expires.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589755/prevent-ajax-timer-control-request-from-extending-formsauthentication-ticket) had similar issue, but the solution is for class .net project and I can't see how I can apply it to my MVC project.

It would be nice if a solution was in a form of an attribute like `[DoNotExtendAuthentication]` which I could slap on an action, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class DoNotExtendAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName
        );
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[Authorize]
[DoNotExtendAuthentication]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It works, to my surprise. Could you please explain why this is the case? Based on the code I'd assume that all it would do is delete authentication cookie after the action is executed. I probably misunderstand the line of events that happen in the pipeline of execution

Comment: Same here. This works but I'm not sure I understand why. Could you please explain what's going on after OnResultExecuted is called? Thanks.

Comment: The Response.Cookies array is empty unless you (or other code) add something to it. It's only meant for adding/updating cookies. By removing the forms auth cookie from the response, you're essentially telling the browser that the auth cookie is still the same and to continue using the original.  The server still actually renewed the auth cookie (by creating a new one), but the new auth cookie is essentially abandoned because the new authentication ticket/value is never sent back in the response.